# Вывести определенную строку из ArrayList

Tags: java, android

Всем привет! Есть `ArrayList:`

```
private static ArrayList<String> subcribeItemIDs = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("s1");
    add("s2");
    add("s3");
    add("s4");
}};
```

К примеру мне нужно вывести только 3 строку (s3), как мне это сделать? Большое спасибо!)

Comment: Что за бред? subcribeItemIDs.get(2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.println(subcribeItemIDs.get(2));
```